# why doesn't user defined function sort the elements of same length in the order given?

Tags: c++, string, sorting, vector

My task is to sort the words of a string in the increasing order of their length and for words of same length, I have to keep them in the order given.
for ex: "to be or not to be" will become "to be or to be not".
i am first making a vector 'v' of all the words in the string and then trying to sort the vector using user defined function in sort() function of C++.
Here is my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
static bool comparelength(string first,string second){//function to compare length
    return first.size()<second.size();
}

int main() {
    string text="Jlhvvd wfwnphmxoa qcuucx qsvqskq cqwfypww dyphntfz hkbwx xmwohi qvzegb ubogo sbdfmnyeim tuqppyipb llwzeug hrsaebveez aszqnvruhr xqpqd ipwbapd mlghuuwvec xpefyglstj dkvhhgecd kry";
    vector<string> v;
    string cur="";
    text+=" ";
    

for(int i=0;i<text.size();i++){
        if(text[i]==32){//if space is encountered then the word is inserted in the vector
            v.push_back(cur);
            cur="";
        }
        else{
            cur+=text[i];//if not space then text[i] is added to the current word
        }
    }
    sort(v.begin(),v.end(),comparelength);//sort the vector
    for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++)
    cout<<v[i]<<" ";
```

Now it gives this output:
"Kry xqpqd ubogo hkbwx qvzegb jlhvvd xmwohi qcuucx qsvqskq llwzeug ipwbapd dyphntfz cqwfypww tuqppyipb dkvhhgecd sbdfmnyeim xpefyglstj mlghuuwvec aszqnvruhr hrsaebveez wfwnphmxoa"

But the correct output should be:
"Kry hkbwx ubogo xqpqd jlhvvd qcuucx xmwohi qvzegb qsvqskq llwzeug ipwbapd cqwfypww dyphntfz tuqppyipb dkvhhgecd wfwnphmxoa sbdfmnyeim hrsaebveez aszqnvruhr mlghuuwvec xpefyglstj"

see the position 1,2 and 3(using 0 indexing).

it should give: hkbwx ubogo xqpqd.

but it gives:   xqpqd ubogo hkbwx.

which makes me think that it is not sorting the words of same length in the order given. You can find many other positions where this happens(for ex: 4,5,6 and 7).

But for the string "leetcode plus try suck geaser is cool best"
it gives the correct output which is: "is try plus suck cool best geaser
leetcode"

Can anyone make it clear why is it not working for the former string but working for the latter.
I've tried doing

```
static bool comparelength(string first,string second){
    if(first.size()==second.size())
    return true;
    if(first.size()<second.size())
    return true;
    else
    return false;
}
```

But this throws runtime error.

sorry for making the question messy but i really want to understand this.

Answer (score 5):

`std::sort` is not stable, ie order of elements that are equivalent is not necessarily preserved. If you get a stable sorting from `std::sort` then this is just by chance. Stable sorting is more expensive (`O(N·log(N)^2)` vs `O(N·log(N))`), hence you have to explicitly ask for it. It can be done with [`std::stable_sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort).

You could use `std::sort` with a custom comparator if you would populate a container of `std::pair<std::string,size_t>` where `second` is the index in the original container. However, I suppose using `std::stable_sort` is simpler.